# Why do we use "someone" to signify one person?

Tags: etymology, language-families, philosophy-of-language, word-formation

I can't come up with a better title so let me just say that I'm sorry for misleading you if this question isn't even close to what you expected.

First of all my **observation**:

In the three languages that I know (swedish, english and spanish), a construction similar to `some + one` is used to signify one person.

- someone = some + one
- någon = några/något + en
- alguien = algo + uno (? I'm not really sure if this actually applies to spanish)

I talked to a friend who is Polish and he told me that in the polish language they have a separate word for `someone`.

Now to my question, which is a twoparter:

**1:**
Could this construction be viewed as strange? With this I mean is it common to go from many (some) to one to construct a word, instead of using lets say something like `many+one`. I realize that this is a very weird question and I'm sorry but I really am having problems formulating this question. I'll happilly try to respond to any comments or requests for clarification.

**2:**

Is this a construct unique for latin/germano/european languages (I know very very little about linguistics so feel free to explain it to me like I'm five)?

Comment: Two things are involved here. One is using the numeral _one_ to represent a human; the other is quantifying that _one_ with an indefinite existential quantifier _some/några/algo_. Both are not uncommon, and the quantifier construction is straightforward. But in a language with classifiers, things work differently; in Malay, 'someone' is _seseorang_. _Orang_ is the classifier for humans (_tiga orang doktor_ 'three doctors') and _se-_ is the clitic form for _satu_ 'one'. _Seorang_ means 'one person', but reduplicated _seseorang_ makes it indefinite 'someone/somebody'.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what's misleading you, but *some* does not have a plural meaning in this case. *Some* can be a plural indefinite as in *some people*, but it can also be a singular indefinite as in *some person*. It doesn't mean "many", in other words.

Comment: I would analyse *some* as having neither a singular nor a plural meaning - rather, it's something quantificational. Semantically, it can be analysed as the existential quantifier. *some boy arrived* means *there is an individual x s.t. x is a boy and x arrived*, whereas *some boys arrived* mens *there is a group of individuals x s.t. that group of individuals arrived*. Check out the SEP entry on generalised quantifiers for more details: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/generalized-quantifiers/

Comment: One interesting question to ask about English specifically is whether *one* in *someone* should be analysed as the (somewhat archaic) gender neutral 3rd person pronoun, e.g. *one should never go shopping alone*, the numeral *one*, or anaphoric one, e.g. *John bought a book, and Sally bought one too*. The fact that *someone* carries an animacy presupposition suggests that the first option is the correct one, but i have no idea how to make this work semantically. A quantifier shouldn't be able to combine with a pronoun.

Comment: Thai seems to work like Malay, except using word order rather than reduplication: neung khon ‘one person’, but khon neung ‘someone’ (neung = one, khon = people classifier.) ‘Some people’ would be bang khon. Thai ESL learners often make the mistake of giving ‘someone’ a plural referent, so clearly this feature of English is a bit strange to them too!

Comment: "Some" does not mean "many".

Comment: *Någon* doesn't come from *några* or *något* fused with *en*. Instead, it is its own inflected form for the common gender, parallel to *något* for the neuter gender, and not derived from it. Similarly, *alguién* comes from Latin *aliquem*, accusative of the word that means directly "someone" (although that is in turn just the masculine or feminine form of the same word, *aliquod*, which went on to form *algo* in Spanish). So while these words have roots that mean "some", it's not "some object" + "people instead". It's directly "some person", or "something not neuter".

Answer (score 2):

It's not strange. As for Polish, one could say "ktoś" (kto-ś - who-some), but there's frequent use of "jeden" (one) and "człowiek" (man) in similar contexts. I think it's just a general grammaticalization tendency.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a phenomenon with a single origin; it probably evolved convergently (separate languages developing the same thing). Swedish's close relative, **Icelandic**, doesn't have this (the word for someone in Icelandic is "einhver", from "einn + hver" = "one + who"), and its even closer relative, **Norwegian**, has "noen" which comes from an Old Norse adjective meaning "some(one/thing)", so it's not a Scandinavian thing, and **German** has a unique word, "jemand", that can't be broken down into parts so it's not even a Germanic thing.

Comment: This is very, very old but Swedish does have a cognate word to noen which is någon.